# htaccess redirect adding text to url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I added this code to my .htaccess file in: https://www.revealio.com/agora

```
Redirect 302 / https://sales.revealio.com/agora?r_done=1
```

This should redirect it to our subdomain that is in the code. The problem is that it redirects to: https://sales.revealio.com/agoraagora

Why is it adding another agora onto the end of the URL. How can I fix this. I have tried commenting out everything in the .htaccess file located at https://www.revealio.com/agora other than the redirect. I also tried these:

```
Redirect 302 / https://sales.revealio.com/agora
Redirect 302 / https://sales.revealio.com/agora/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` for precise regex based matching:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^ https://sales.revealio.com/agora?r_done=1
```

Make sure to test from a new browser or clear your browser cache completely.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!